# Appending an URL to an existing link

Tags: jquery

I have links on a page. I want to be able to append the the URL the links are going to; for example, here's what an existing link looks like:

```
<a href="/url/urlpage.ext">Click here</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

I want to be able to, using jQuery, go through all the links on the page and append to the beginning of the URL, if they don't have an http, add it... so the end URL looks like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/url/urlpage.ext">Click here</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Comment: This is possible, but SO isn't a place to ask others to write your code from scratch. Have you made an attempt? If so, please show your code and explain how it doesn't quite meet your expectations. If you are not comfortable writing the code, you may need to consult a professional developer for assistance.

Comment: Be careful of relative versus absolute URLs here.  Could the page be a few folders into the site and thus you'd have to reconstruct a path?

Comment: If you're doing this to make sure that all your relative links send you to the `www` version of your website then this is not the way to do this. If that's true, search around for how to redirect from non-www to www.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to change your softcoded (relative) URLs into hardcoded (absolute) URLs? It's faster to use relative links because you avoid unnecessary routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

```
$("a:not([href^=http])").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.mysite.com'+$(this).attr('href'))
});
```

Comment: +1 - I always like to point out that many jQuery functions accept functions to mutate an attribute: `$(this).attr('href', function(_, href){ 'foo' + href });`

Comment: thanks a lot. That worked out great! What does this mean:[href^=http]?

Comment: @Damien the jQuery selector is as follows: select anchor tags that do not have an href attribute beginning with 'http'

Comment: Damien missed this question. @kyle thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    //Get the current href
    var href = $(this).attr("href");

    //Check for http in the beginning
    if (href.indexOf("http://") == -1) {

        //Add to it and set it
        href = "http://" + href;
        $(this).attr("href", href);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//for every <a>
$('a').each(function() {
    // get existing href
    var href= $(this).attr('href'),
    // start at the beginning, get first 7 chars
    var first7char = href.substr(0, 7);
    // if not http or https
    if(first7char !== 'http://' || 'https://'){
        // insert  http://
    $(this).attr('href', 'http://' + href');
    }
});
```